# Multiple-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I try to run this code. It means that insert values into another table. However, it displays

> The multiple-identifier AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID could not be bound.

I also put quote [] but it got same errors. I tried to use select into query as well.

```
INSERT INTO AMLDB.AML0001.GWGBENUT
    select 
     isnull(substring(AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID,1,5),'')+isnull(substring(AMLETL.ADD_USER.EMAIL,4,5), ''),
       usersequence.NEXTVAL USERID,
   AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID,
   AMLETL.ADD_USER.USERNAME, 
 'demo',
 to_char(getdate(),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'),
 AMLETL.ADD_USER.USERTYPE,
 '0001',
 'en',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'N',
 '0',
 '',
 'oZlZp6YtyqfWFzQh6Jde7g==',
 '0001',to_char(getdate(),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'),
 '9999','','N','0','','H','','',
 AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID,'J','','','','','0001',AMLETL.ADD_USER.branch
 from AMLETL.ADD_USER where len(AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID)>10   
 ;
```

Supposed that All column name, branch is correct. It shows The multi-part identifier "AMLETL.ADD_UserID" could not be bound

Comment: _multiple-part could not be bound_ is not the full error message, Please post the full message. Also I don't think SQL Server has `TO_CHAR` it seems like you are using _Oracle_ not _SQL Server_

Comment: Please also read up on aliases. They allow you to give a short-hand name for the tables in your `FROM` clause which means you don't have to repeat the full database and table name everywhere you refer to it elsewhere in the query (also completely unnecessary, of course, if as here you're only referencing one table anyway)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever same error with table_name.columnname only

Comment: Edit your question and include full error message for clarity

Comment: @HungNguyen Do you really have _UserID_ in _AMLETL.ADD_USER_?

Comment: @Sami Of course yes

Comment: @HungNguyen When you comment this line `--INSERT INTO AMLDB.AML0001.GWGBENUT` and run the query what happen?

Comment: @Sami same error

Comment: SQL Server doesn't tend to *lie* in it's error messages. If it's saying that `AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID` doesn't exist, you need to check, double-check and triple-check for typos.

Comment: @HungNguyen Would be easier if you can show us your table structures.

Answer (score 0):

`to_char` is not T-SQL method. It is a Oracle operator. Use `CONVERT` and aliases:

```
INSERT INTO AMLDB.AML0001.GWGBENUT
SELECT
ISNULL(substring(u.UserID,1,5),'')
    + isnull(substring(u.EMAIL,4,5), ''),
usersequence.NEXTVAL USERID,
u.UserID,
u.USERNAME, 
 'demo',
 convert(varchar(50),GETDATE(), 112) YourColumn,
 u.USERTYPE,
 '0001',
 'en',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'N',
 '0',
 '',
 'oZlZp6YtyqfWFzQh6Jde7g==',
 '0001',
 convert(varchar(50),GETDATE(), 112) YourColumnVARCHAR,
 '9999','','N','0','','H','','',
 u.UserID,'J','','','','','0001',
 u.branch
 from AMLETL.ADD_USER u where len(AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID) > 10
```

Comment: I've changed from to_char to format. However, root cause is not here.

Comment: Sorry. It's convert. Thanks

Comment: @HungNguyen please, see my updated question. Try to use table aliases. I've edited my query to use table aliases.

Comment: @HungNguyen does it help to you?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have a proper join between the tables. You need to join them on the primary key, below I have assumed it is UserId and that  AMLDB.AML0001.GWGBENUT has the same name for the column

Change this

```
from AMLETL.ADD_USER where len(AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID) > 10
```

to

```
FROM AMLETL.ADD_USER au
JOIN  AMLDB.AML0001.GWGBENUT g ON au.UserID = g.UserID 
WHERE LEN(au.UserID) > 10
```

Comment: it happens from this line isnull(substring(AMLETL.ADD_USER.UserID,1,5), '')